# Is there a way to create a fallback image in CSS in the event that a browser does not support a certain file type?

Tags: css, image, sass

I recently learned that I can create fallback images in HTML as follows:

```
      <picture>
        <source srcset="img/nat-1-large.webp" />
        <img
          src="img/nat-1-large.jpg"
          alt="Photo 1"
          class="composition__photo composition__photo--p1"
        />
      </picture>
```

My understanding is that the above is particularly useful if you have users whose web browsers might not support the webp file format. I am wondering if there is a way to go about doing this in css as well. I have the following CSS code:

```
&--3 {
  background-image: url(../img/nat-5.webp);
}
```

Is there currently a way to have a jpg file displayed should the browser not support the webp image?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to comma separate the background images.

```
background: URL(img/background.jpg), URL(img/backgroud.webp)
```

I tested this in IE11 which caniuse.com says doesn't support webp and it worked.

Comment: in your case the JPG will always be the one shown since it's on the top (whataver the support of the webp one)

Comment: To add to what @TemaniAfif said, you will load both files.

Comment: If it loads both files, that wouldn’t work. I want the jpg to load only if the webp (the more efficient file type) is not supported by the browser.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you could check to see if the browser supports js and then load the right image from there.